# Where can I buy a Chagaz in Brooklyn?

Tags: product-recommendation, yom-tov, cooking-bishul

There is an instrument, called [Chagaz](http://www.zomet.org.il/eng/?CategoryID=250&ArticleID=112), that uses a timer to off the gas, after I cook on YomTov. It's a product from the [Zomet Institute](http://www.zomet.org.il/) in Israel.

Do you know where can I buy it in Brooklyn?

Comment: Drimmers is a large appliance store on Coney Island Avenue in Flatbush. They seem to have a large Orthodox cliental. If they don't have this device they may be able to guide you.